# moving server can not login

Tags: login, user-access, server, linux, windows

I design my site in win7 system, and today before a server rent, I moving my blog from win7 to my another computer witch is installed CentOS 5.5 for a last test,  I have reference the article http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

moving my site from `d:/www/` to `/var/www/html`, and my site runs well, all the post, comment have no problem.

But I can not login into my site. I have two test accounts, one is admin, another is normal user, both account can not login into. when I fill with the username and password, click login button, then page will refresh and do nothing still return to the login page with no error hint. I searched google with a ton of posts, I have tried to rename the plugin folder, clear the web browser's cookies...

Sorry for I can not test a password forget and register, because I have't install any mail scripts in localhost.

Waiting for a possible solution, regards.

Comment: Are you using WAMP, XAMP, or something else?

Comment: @Jeremy Jared, in windows I use WAMP. but in CentOS, i install mysql, php via `yum` from mysql and php official downloads `tar.gz` package. then input full wordpress database, change wp_options site url and home to new, so my site's other links all runs well. but just the login issue... I can not login into admin panel to rebuilt permelink for a new .htaccss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this strange problem by myself. Share my experience to all.

Find these 2 lines in `/etc/php.ini`

```
upload_max_filesize 16M 

post_max_size 16M
```

Add common before, so that change as:

```
;upload_max_filesize 16M 

;post_max_size 16M
```

And final, do not forget restart apache: `service httpd restart` via SSH.

Then I could login into my site under linux as the win7 system.

Comment: I really don't see ANY relation at all between these PHP settings and a login page not working - ordinary a password reset delivered to a local mailbox should have done the trick.
If it really fixed it, something must be messed up with your PHP installation/configuration.

Comment: Having similar problem and this did nothing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may need to modify some data in your database.

Assuming your table prefix is `wp_` and your database is `wordpress`...

1) Open up the database Admin

2) Look under the `wp_options` table and look for `siteurl` verify it is correct.

3) If you have multisite, look under each `wp_XX_options` and verify the `siteurl` is correct.

4) Head to the login page... and login

5) **Problem Solved.** (hopefully)

Comment: hi, I have only one site, build width wp3.2 and buddypress. I have changed the wp_options, `siteurl` and `home` to new, so my site's other links all runs well. but just the login issue...