# Moving from one host to another - cannot access the dashboard

Tags: login, hosting, migration, wp-login-form

I'm having a problem with my WordPress installation. I'm trying to move it from one host to another (switching hosting providers for my sites). I was following the instructions given [here](http://blog.triphp.com/how-to/how-to-move-wordpress-to-a-new-server-or-host.html), and everything went smoothly except for one little thing: I can no longer access the dashboard.

Similar to this (unanswered) question: [moving server can not login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38536/moving-server-can-not-login)

The site works, I can see all the posts, all the uploaded pictures, all the comments and tags - everything is there and available. I just cannot access the dashboard. Password recovery didn't help, and doesn't seem to be the problem. It doesn't complain, just clears the fields when I click "log in" and stays on the login page.

Note that the domain name doesn't change, I switched servers, but the domain remains the same.

What could be the problem, and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you updated the settings in wp_options via phpmyadmin for the home URL?

Comment: @neak the URL hasn't changed.

Comment: Did you try clearing the browser cache?

Comment: Yup... Tried with a different browser... doesn't matter

Comment: Couple of questions - Are you running a page cache plugin at all? and also has the database changed at all?

Comment: I don't run any page cache plugins to the best of my knowledge. DB shouldn't have changed. I exported the MySQL DB from the old server, imported on a brand new one.

Comment: did you upload whole site in your server or you installed wordpress previously and tried to import the db? in case you already installed wordpress in your server and import the db, you have to put your login informaton from that site from where you imported the db in your server. nb: this is more like a comment, but i couldn't find a place to comment here. sorry for that.

Comment: @maksbd19 you put it in the right place, its ok:) I uploaded the whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deleting that copy of the installation, and cloning my site using the [manageWP](http://managewp.com/) plugin instead. That worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the AUTH_SALT (and SECURE_AUTH_SALT) from your wp-config.php should fix it

Comment: that sounds like something that might be related. But I'm past that (see my answer), so can't verify.

Comment: Sure, just documenting for the next one :)

Answer (score 0):

- Disable via SQL administration tool plugin who controls logins. Wp
  lock or something, there are many of them. If you used one of those.

  - See apache access/error logs for details what happens when you try to
    login, what HTTP code you get, maybe it's redirect or something.

Answer (score 0):

you having problem to see with admin dashboard. firstly you re-uplaod the  admin folder through the ftp. what ever you choose the uploading manner..

go upload original Admin folder which is downloaded you first one site.

your problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, first put this in the bottom of your wp-config file to force url location:

`define('WP_HOME','yourSiteUrlHere');
define('WP_SITEURL','yourSiteUrlHere');`

The ONLY thing that worked for me to log in is using the "emergency.php" script. It forces WP to let you in. Go here for more info on making the script: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/User:MichaelH/Orphaned_Plugins_needing_Adoption/Emergency